Comparison of isolation methods in Android
Where can I find a table that compares what information is and is-not accessible from an Android app with various isolation methods?
I need to install a piece of malware on my Android device. This is definitely a very dangerous app that was designed by someone powerful, malicious, and actively trying to attack me. I don't want them to learn anything about my device, and I definitely don't want their app to see any data on my device or be able to interact with other apps or files on the device (even with an accidental tap caused by me clicking something after the app spawned maliciously-timed INTENT).
On desktop, I use QubesOS. So I have no issue running and playing with malware. I just fire-up a new DispVM, and I'm very confident that it's isolated. Android, however, leaks so much info to apps that I'm not sure how best to go about this.
I've considered a few isolation methods:

Do nothing (default app "sandboxing"),
Install in a Work Profile (eg Insular),
Install in a new User Profile,
Buy (and install it on) a second phone, or
Something even better?

Is there any table that lists all of the data that is made available to apps that are compartimienalized with each of these methods?

Android Emulator

Installing a known malware where you don't exactly understand what malicious actions can be preformed by it is always a risk. Even with a recent Google Pixel device fully patched with the latest update installing a malware is a risk. Therefore I would never install a malware on a device that you use for any other purpose other than installing this malware. Android Emulator is also a possibility but keep in mind that emulators can have security problems that may allow a malware to escape.
